# Magento Module Permissions

Tags: magento

I have a modules for Magento, when I try to assign permissions for other users apart from Admin role to the module (check the checkbox) when I click save it unchecks the box. I have looked through other solutions but still wasn't able to solve it. Please kindly help.

```html
<config>
    <modules>
        <D3_Newsladdressimport>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </D3_Newsladdressimport>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <newsladdressimport>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>D3_Newsladdressimport</module>
                    <frontName>newsladdressimport</frontName>
                </args>
            </newsladdressimport>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <newsladdressimport>
                    <file>newsladdressimport.xml</file>
                </newsladdressimport>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
   <newsladdressimport>
    <use>admin</use>
    <args>
     <module>D3_Newsladdressimport</module>
     <frontName>newsladdressimport</frontName>
    </args>
   </newsladdressimport>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
  <menu>
   <newsletter>
    <children>
     <newsladdressimport module="newsladdressimport">
      <title>Newsletter Address Import</title>
      <sort_order>71</sort_order>
      <action>newsladdressimport/adminhtml_newsladdressimport</action>
     </newsladdressimport>
    </children>
   </newsletter>
  </menu>
  <acl>
   <resources>
    <all>
     <title>Allow Everything</title>
    </all>
    <admin>
     <children>
      <newsletter>
       <children>
        <D3_Newsladdressimport>
         <title>Newsladdressimport Module</title>
         <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        </D3_Newsladdressimport>
       </children>
      </newsletter>
     </children>
    </admin>
   </resources>
  </acl>
  <layout>
   <updates>
    <newsladdressimport>
     <file>newsladdressimport.xml</file>
    </newsladdressimport>
   </updates>
  </layout>
  <translate>
            <modules>
                <newsladdressimport>
                    <files>
                        <default>D3_Newsladdressimport.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </newsladdressimport>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <newsladdressimport>
                <class>D3_Newsladdressimport_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>newsladdressimport_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </newsladdressimport>
            <newsladdressimport_mysql4>
                <class>D3_Newsladdressimport_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <newsladdressimport>
                        <table>newsladdressimport</table>
                    </newsladdressimport>
                </entities>
            </newsladdressimport_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <newsladdressimport_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>D3_Newsladdressimport</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </newsladdressimport_setup>
            <newsladdressimport_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </newsladdressimport_write>
            <newsladdressimport_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </newsladdressimport_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <newsladdressimport>
                <class>D3_Newsladdressimport_Block</class>
            </newsladdressimport>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <newsladdressimport>
                <class>D3_Newsladdressimport_Helper</class>
            </newsladdressimport>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code for working access right.

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <D3_Newsladdressimport>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </D3_Newsladdressimport>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <newsladdressimport>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>D3_Newsladdressimport</module>
                    <frontName>newsladdressimport</frontName>
                </args>
            </newsladdressimport>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <newsladdressimport>
                    <file>newsladdressimport.xml</file>
                </newsladdressimport>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <newsladdressimport>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>D3_Newsladdressimport</module>
                    <frontName>newsladdressimport</frontName>
                </args>
            </newsladdressimport>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <newsletter>
                <children>
                    <newsladdressimport module="newsladdressimport">
                        <title>Newsletter Address Import</title>
                        <sort_order>71</sort_order>
                        <action>newsladdressimport/adminhtml_newsladdressimport</action>
                    </newsladdressimport>
                </children>
            </newsletter>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <newsletter>
                            <children>
                                <newsladdressimport>
                                    <title>Newsletter Address Import</title>
                                    <sort_order>71</sort_order>
                                </newsladdressimport>
                            </children>
                        </newsletter>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <newsladdressimport>
                    <file>newsladdressimport.xml</file>
                </newsladdressimport>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <newsladdressimport>
                    <files>
                        <default>D3_Newsladdressimport.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </newsladdressimport>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <newsladdressimport>
                <class>D3_Newsladdressimport_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>newsladdressimport_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </newsladdressimport>
            <newsladdressimport_mysql4>
                <class>D3_Newsladdressimport_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <newsladdressimport>
                        <table>newsladdressimport</table>
                    </newsladdressimport>
                </entities>
            </newsladdressimport_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <newsladdressimport_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>D3_Newsladdressimport</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </newsladdressimport_setup>
            <newsladdressimport_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </newsladdressimport_write>
            <newsladdressimport_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </newsladdressimport_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <newsladdressimport>
                <class>D3_Newsladdressimport_Block</class>
            </newsladdressimport>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <newsladdressimport>
                <class>D3_Newsladdressimport_Helper</class>
            </newsladdressimport>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

In your code you have made following mistake.
You have to give same name identifier in menu as well as in acl.

```
<menu>
            <newsletter>
                <children>
                    <newsladdressimport module="newsladdressimport">
                        <title>Newsletter Address Import</title>
                        <sort_order>71</sort_order>
                        <action>newsladdressimport/adminhtml_newsladdressimport</action>
                    </newsladdressimport>
                </children>
            </newsletter>
        </menu>
```

here you have given name `<newsladdressimport module="newsladdressimport">`
and in ACL you have given `<D3_Newsladdressimport>`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you very much... It works now! single mistake gave me headache :)